# Tornado vs Apache for django?

Tags: django, apache, tornado, high-availability

I have a web application whose stack is Ubuntu + Apache/mod_wsgi + Django + MySQL, this web application faces heavy traffic, sometimes which leads to delay in response time and heavy CPU usage due to request queueing.

Will it be of any point if i replace Apache with Tornado ?

I am completely new to Tornado, so any text on how Tornado and django can be used will be helpful, in case it is suitable for my situation.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to replace Apache with Tornado.  It is possible to run Django on Tornado, but that really only makes sense as part of a transition from pure Django to pure Tornado.  If you want to keep Django you should stay with a dedicated WSGI server (if you're looking for alternatives to apache, consider gunicorn or uwsgi).

Comment: So is Tornado is replacement of django ? because as per the stats i am looking at the traffic handling capability of Totnado is far above django.

Comment: Tornado is an alternative to django, but I wouldn't call it a "replacement" because it doesn't try to do everything that django does.